# Focus on two widgets - Android

Tags: android, leanback, xml-drawable

I need to highlight widgets as per the following design, In below design all three widgets are highlighted in red when the cursor reaches the position

[image]

I have written the following code to achieve above:

**left_strip_color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/focus_color"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/focus_color"  />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_list_bg" />
</selector>
```

**leftmenu_text_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/focus_color"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/focus_color"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/white"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**leftmenu_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/left_strip_color_selector"></View>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>

    <com.zeenews.tv.base.BaseTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/left_menu_text"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/leftmenu_text_selector"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

</androidx.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingLinearLayout>
```

Note: For now, I have implemented the above code for red strip and menu text only

With the above code, I am getting below effects when I move the cursor from one menu option to another (only strip is getting colored and text is not getting colored.)

[image]

My Question: Am I doing something wrong? Can two widgets receive focus at the same time? Can I achieve these effects using any other standard coding practice?